# ICACLS behaving weird when executed from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2008, cmd, windows-7-x64

One of the feature i missed most from Windows 2003 and earlier is the ability to assign the same NTFS permission to multiple folder. This feature is no longer available in windows 2008, and i need to use icacls. This is my question. If i typed in:

```
 FOR /F %i IN (D:\Sample\Sample.txt) DO ICACLS /grant "IIS_IUSRS":(OI)(CI)F
```

directly into command prompt, everything works fine saying Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files. HOWEVER, if i store the above command into a .bat file, and execute that batch file, it's failing to execute

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the command line you prefix a FOR variable with a single percent. Within a batch file you must prefix the FOR variable with two percents - `%%i`.